# Custom numbers in input type="number"

Tags: html, css

Can I add to my input type="number" custom values?
I would like to put in only : 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 and 32.

Now I can't find other options than steps or max/min, but I don't know how can I do with this.

Hope you help me,
Greets

Comment: No, you can't do that with a custom type. However, you can use the `pattern` attribute and give a regular expression to validate the input. However, not all browsers supports this new HTML5 attribute (there are still old computers with IE7 or IE8 !). If you know that 1,2,4,8,16,32 are the only acceptable values, why don't use use a `SELECT` tag instead ???

Answer (score 1):

you can't do this with `<input type="number">`
but this may work for you:

```
<input list="numbers" type="list" />
<datalist id="numbers">
    <option value="1">
    <option value="2">
    <option value="4">
    <option value="8">
    <option value="16">
    <option value="32">
</datalist>
```